# I can't use bootstrap live search in my data with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, search, live

I'm importing data from ajax into the table, but

```
<select class = "selectpicker" data-live-search = "true">
```

does not work even though I add,
my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
          url:'/sbadmin/pages/server/get_brand.php',
          type:'GET',
          success:function(result){
            $('#data').html(result);
          }
        });
```

to table

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control form-control-xs" onChange="window.location.href=this.value" id="data" data-live-search="true">
    </select>
```

get_brand.php

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_id>1 ORDER BY brand_name asc');
$stmt->execute();
$brands = $stmt->fetchAll();
?> <option><-- Choose Brand --></option> <?php
foreach ($brands as $brand)
{
    ?>

    <option data-tokens="<?php echo $user['brand_name'] ?>" value="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/sbadmin/pages/order/pharmcy/add-pharmacy-order.php?brand_id=<?php echo $brand['brand_id'] ?>"><a href=""><?php echo $brand['brand_name'] ?></a></option>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: my code result : [link](https://pasteboard.co/IHGRI0t.png)

Comment: your goal is to fill the drop down values with db values right?

Comment: @Aroon Thanks for reply, I'm filling in, I just can't perform live search with bootstrap data-live-search = "true" tag

Answer (score 0):

since you are not passing any values in AJAX, please try like below. I didn't test but it will work

```
            <?php
            function dropValues() { 
          #put connection establishment for DB or declare it globally
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_id>1 ORDER BY brand_name asc');
            $stmt->execute();
            $brands = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $txt = "";
            foreach ($brands as $brand)
            {
           #edit with your option values. I'm just giving the example.
              $txt .= '<option data-tokens="'.$user['brand_name'].'" value="'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'">$some value</option> ';

            }
            return $txt;
            }


            ?>

            <select class="selectpicker form-control form-control-xs" onChange="someFunction(this)" id="data" data-live-search="true">
            <?php echo dropValues();?>
                </select>
    <script>
    function someFunction(this) { 
    var val = this.val();

    //ajax function here to get the data
    //send the val to php page and get result and append it to drop down



    }

</script>
```

Your ajax php page is completely out of syntax. plz visit here for more info about ajax https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I'm sorry I'm already doing this, and my goal is to look for the results live